# How to get namespace from Type in TypeScript AST?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-ast

I am traversing a method using the TS compiler API and the method has some return type.

I need info over that type, like what package it is from and if it is exposed under a namespace.

Is this possible using Typescript AST?

Answer (score 0):

Some types are created in-place, for example, if your function is declared to return an intersection type, the best you can do is to look at each type  in the intersection.

But sometimes, a type has a `symbol` property and that symbol can have `declarations` (more than one declaration if the type is a merged interface, for example). Each declaration is a `Node` so you can use `node.getSourceFile()` to find its source file (then it's relatively easy to find a package), and walk `node.parent` chain to look for containing namespace (check for `node.flags & NodeFlags.Namespace`).